If you exile a Dryad Arbor with Hazel's Brewmaster can all your foods tap for a green mana?
If you exile a Dryad Arbor with Hazel's Brewmaster can your food tokens tap for a green mana?

Yes, because Dryad Arbor has the ability ": add ." while it is in exile, it will give that ability to all of the foods a player controls if they exile it with Hazel's Brewmaster.
The rule that gives mana abilities to objects with basic land types is 305.6:

305.6 The basic land types are Plains, Island, Swamp, Mountain, and Forest. If an object uses the words “basic land type,” it’s referring to one of these subtypes. An object with the land card type and a basic land type has the intrinsic ability “: Add [mana symbol],” even if the text box doesn’t actually contain that text or the object has no text box. For Plains, [mana symbol] is ; for Islands, ; for Swamps, ; for Mountains, ; and for Forests, . See rule 107.4a. See also rule 605, “Mana Abilities.”

It's important that the rules say an object here. Object is defined in Magic by rule 109.1:

109.1 An object is an ability on the stack, a card, a copy of a card, a token, a spell, a permanent, or an emblem.

All cards are objects in Magic, regardless of what zone they are in, so the rule giving cards with basic land types the ability to tap for mana works in all zones, including exile. It also describes the ability as intrinsic, an ability that the card just has, not one that is granted, so it isn't applied in the layer system (which could create dependencies with Hazel's Brewmaster) it applies at all times, even outside the game, which is why a deck that runs Dryad Arbor can use Zirda, the Dawnwaker as a companion, since 305.6 even applies during deck construction.

My immediate answer is "yes".

Dryad Arbor is a creature.
Dryad Arbor has the ability "{T}: Add {G}" as a consequence of being a Forest (CR 305.6). This meets the template for an activated ability "[Cost]: [Effect]" (CR 602.1).

This therefore meets the conditions on Hazel's Brewmaster, so foods you control gain "{T}: Add {G}".
